# Is it possible to edit an Azure Automation Schedule?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I have created a schedule for an Azure Automation Runbook, and linked the schedule to the Runbook. However I notice that one cannot edit the schedule, or even delete the schedule. I may be missing something. It seems one can just create Automation schedules. Please note I am not talking about the Azure Scheduler here with its "Job Collections " etc.

Would appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: are you using preview portal or old one?

Comment: Old one.... Thats sounds like a hint....

Comment: @BrunoFaria,  Just tried new portal, still read only. Basically can "delete" or "unlink" only, unless I am missing something.

Comment: You can't edit. You have to delete and create a new one.

Comment: @BrunoFaria, Thanks for this. This is a bit frustrating. Seems a major restriction to me. Perhaps I need to feed this back to MS as an enhancement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete and unlink a schedule in both the old portal and the preview one.  You cannot edit the time or frequency of the schedule though.  Please vote for this on [UserVoice](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-azure-automation/suggestions/7655052-update-the-scheduler-after-creation) so that the product team can prioritize this.

To unlink in the old portal, select the runbook > click schedule > highlight the schedule to remove > click the unlink button at the bottom right.

To delete a schedule in the old portal, go to Assets > highlight the schedule to delete > click the delete button on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks I had posted my own feature request, not knowing about this one, however I have now upvoted it. Thanks.

Comment: It appears that you cannot edit the parameters associated with a schedule either which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't edit Azure Automation schedules, you can hook up Azure Automation runbooks to start based on Azure Scheduler jobs, and I think you can edit those scheduled jobs. Please see http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/08/05/scheduling-azure-automation-runbooks-with-azure-scheduler-2/ for more info.